# unscrollable content + unclickable hyperlink in webpage bar

Tags: html, css, header, position, footer

i'm having this problem that my page is not scrollable through the whole content after the bar.also, i want to fit image after the bar to the size of the page so it won't be any right or left gap and the text after the image to be aligned in the center .lastly the shopping cart and the user are not clickable for some reason although i made them with an `<a>` tag 
screenshot of the output i want the image to fit this whole part from left to right:
[image]
their is no scroll to see the whole content of the `<P>` tag
[image]
The css code::

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.header{
   height: 80px;
 width: 100%;
    background: url(images/header.jpeg);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
}
.bar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 43px;
    background: url(images/menu-boarder.jpeg);
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.mark_colour{
    background-color: pink;
}

.container .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
    background-color: pink;
}
body{
     margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 80%;
}
.menu{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 10px;

}
.menu li{
    display: inline-block;

}
.menu li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;

}
.menu li a:hover{
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 7px;
  position: relative;
  right:80px;


}

.searchTerm {
  width: 400%;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 20px;
}

.searchTerm:focus{
  color: #000000;
}




.homeage_but {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.searchButton {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background: #000000;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.fa-shopping-cart, .glyphicon-user{

    color: #000000;

}
#lblCartCount {
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: crimson;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.form-inline {
   display: flex;

}
.banner{overflow:hidden}
.banner img{width:100%}
.centered-element{text-align:center}

.footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(images/footer.jpeg);
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-bottom: 0px;

}
```

The html code ::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
<title>Cookie|Bakery shop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
        </div>
    <br><br><br><br>
 <div class="bar">
        <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Product</a></li>
        </ul>



      <div class="search">
         <form class="form-inline">
              <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
              <button type="submit" class="searchButton"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> 
            </form> 
     <div class="icons"><!-- here is the unclickable part --------------------------------------------->
     <a herf="xx.html" ><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" style="font-size:36px; margin-right: 10px;">
          <asp:Label ID="lblCartCount" ForeColor="White"/>3</i></a>
     <a herf="" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="font-size:30px; margin-right: 5px; "></i></a>
     </div>
     </div>


     </div>

    <!-- Image of a product with button refrence to the product it self  -->
    <div class="container">
<div class="banner">
<img src="images/cake.jpg" alt="">
     <button class="btn" >CLICK ME!</button>
</div>
         </div>
<div class="centered-element">
    <h4><center><u><mark class="mark_colour">Welome to our Bakery shop!</mark></u></center></h4>
    <p>
       Lorem ipnam dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Sed felis turpis, ulturicies nee herndrerit a
      ullarneorper in maars Donee a erat molestie, condimentum ex eu, vehicula elst Ut egestas consectenor
      libero, et dictum elir tineidunt sed Sed tellus nisi, faciliais sut nulla eu, euismod blandit marpia. Praesent
      uficies semper auctor. Quisque eftieitur sollacstudin metus pec porta. Donec bbero notla, accumsan ut
      negue sit amet, tincsdurt facilisis felis. Phasellus ac ante pretium, vehicula ex sed, feugsat ipsum Nullam
      dapibus erat vitae ligula venenatis vestibulum Morbi aliquam sapien eu volutpet volutpat. Quisquue
      sapien nisl, pulvinar eu finabua eget, tempus quis ante Cras sed blandst eros. Quisque posuere eros at
      tellus tincidtant tristique.

    </p>
</div>








    <div  class="footer">


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does that mean "page is not scrollable through the whole content after the bar" ? please explain a bit.

Comment: @Kevin I'm sorry I didn't make it clear. I meant that my web page has a header for the logo and a bar for the menu bar that also contains the shopping cart and user icon for login and sign up. I hope it is clear now

Comment: little bit clear, can you send a screenshot also? cause your html didnt make it clear in fiddle

Comment: @Kevin sure!!! I will do it right now

Comment: yup................... is your website online ? mean can i get the link?

Comment: yes it is a bakery shop!

Comment: throw the link please

Comment: oh! i think i understood you wrong i meant this an online website for our project and i'm not quite familiar of how to provide you the link....

Comment: If you may i can send it via email????

Comment: Check the fiddle. hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding I made this fiddle for your " after bar " image. Take a look. I have reEdited this.

`<a herf="xx.html"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" style="font-size:36px; margin-right: 10px;">`

`<a herf=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="font-size:30px; margin-right: 5px; "></i></a>`

You need to correct `herf` to `href` --- you mistaken to type. **This will solve your clicking problem.**

For your other problem, please tell me do you want to expand the "Cake image" that is on banner?

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.header{
   height: 80px;
 width: 100%;
    background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1600x400);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
}
.bar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 43px;
    background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1600x400);
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.mark_colour{
    background-color: pink;
}

.container .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
    background-color: pink;
}
body{
     margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 80%;
}
.menu{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 10px;

}
.menu li{
    display: inline-block;

}
.menu li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;

}
.menu li a:hover{
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 7px;
  position: relative;
  right:80px;


}

.searchTerm {
  width: 400%;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  height: 20px;
}

.searchTerm:focus{
  color: #000000;
}




.homeage_but {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.searchButton {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background: #000000;
  padding-right: 8px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.fa-shopping-cart, .glyphicon-user{

    color: #000000;

}
#lblCartCount {
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: crimson;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.form-inline {
   display: flex;

}
.banner{overflow:hidden}
.banner img{width:100%}
.centered-element{text-align:center}

.footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/1600x400);
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-bottom: 0px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cookie|Bakery shop</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br>
  <div class="bar">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Product</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="search">
      <form class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
        <button type="submit" class="searchButton"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </form>
      <div class="icons">
        <!-- here is the unclickable part --------------------------------------------->
        <a herf="xx.html"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" style="font-size:36px; margin-right: 10px;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblCartCount" ForeColor="White" />3</i></a>
        <a herf=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="font-size:30px; margin-right: 5px; "></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Image of a product with button refrence to the product it self  -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="banner">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt="">
      <button class="btn">CLICK ME!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="centered-element">
    <h4>
      <center><u><mark class="mark_colour">Welome to our Bakery shop!</mark></u></center>
    </h4>
    <p>
      Lorem ipnam dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Sed felis turpis, ulturicies nee herndrerit a
      ullarneorper in maars Donee a erat molestie, condimentum ex eu, vehicula elst Ut egestas consectenor
      libero, et dictum elir tineidunt sed Sed tellus nisi, faciliais sut nulla eu, euismod blandit marpia. Praesent
      uficies semper auctor. Quisque eftieitur sollacstudin metus pec porta. Donec bbero notla, accumsan ut
      negue sit amet, tincsdurt facilisis felis. Phasellus ac ante pretium, vehicula ex sed, feugsat ipsum Nullam
      dapibus erat vitae ligula venenatis vestibulum Morbi aliquam sapien eu volutpet volutpat. Quisquue
      sapien nisl, pulvinar eu finabua eget, tempus quis ante Cras sed blandst eros. Quisque posuere eros at
      tellus tincidtant tristique.

    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And for your clicking problems, I suggest you to add `display:block` to search and cart `<a>` tag.

Comment: Wait there are some problems how can I show it to you?

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: I want the image to expand from left to right to the page. And the p tag is still I can't scroll to see it all. As for the clicking problem I tried your suggestion and unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: I added screen shots in to the question to indicate the problem

Comment: I need a link where I could inspect element as well.